# Can you apply multiple hover properties to the same element?

Tags: html, css

I want something to happen on hover for my element, but I also want that hover to trigger changes for another class.

Here is what I have tried:

```
.meet:hover{
    color:#EE3A43 !important;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.3) !important;
}

.meet:hover .trainerContent{
    opacity:.3;
}
```

Is what I am trying to achieve possible with just CSS?

Comment: show your html!

Comment: this answered question may can help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered

Comment: No problem. Second decalration will alter the child element with class `trainerContent` when its parent  with class `meet` is hovered.

Comment: Yes, as long `.trainerContent` is a child of `.meet`.

Comment: @TodorSimeonov this code is not working though. The div with class "trainerContent" does not show opacity when I hover my mouse over the div with class "meet".

Comment: Is `trainerContent` a child of `meet`? Placing the HTML could be useful.

Comment: @AndrewMcCracken *"this code is not working though"* show us the full code that isn't working so we can see.

Comment: @MichaelCoker and somebody upvoted  the question ...

Comment: Lets close it .....

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: so what you mean is when you hover over an element, another element would make some changes on its style?